# How do I make a 50/50 probability for a jQuery function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, function, probability

I have this function:

```
$(document).on("click",".battleOne",function() {

});
```

I want there to be a 50% probability for one of two events occuring on the function:

event # 1:

```
coins += 5;
alert("Your dog won the battle!\n+ 5 coins");
```

event # 2:

```
coins -= 1;
alert("Your dog died in battle :(\n- 5 coins");
```

So essentially I want:

```
$(document).on("click",".battleOne",function() {

//50% chance of this happening:
coins += 5;
alert("Your dog won the battle!\n+ 5 coins");

//50% chance of this happening:
coins -= 1;
alert("Your dog died in battle :(\n- 5 coins");

});
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Take a look at JavaScript `random` method

Answer (score 4):

You can use the [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random) method. It returns a random value between 0 and 1. Here is a quick example:

```
$(document).on("click",".battleOne",function() {
    if(Math.random() < 0.5) {
        coins += 5;
        alert("Your dog won the battle!\n+ 5 coins");
    } else {
        coins -= 5;
        alert("Your dog died in battle :(\n- 5 coins");
    }
});
```

Obviously, `coins` would need to be some kind of global variable accessible in the function scope.

Comment: Worked perfectly! Yeah, I'd already initialized variables and whatnot, I just didn't include the whole script in this post. Thanks a lot, though :)

Comment: Minor nitpick, but you'd have to check for `Math.random() >= 0.5` or `Math.random() < 0.5` for it to truly be a 50/50 chance (because the result ranges from 0 to 1, but doesn't actually include 1).

Answer (score 1):

Use a [random number](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_random.asp) between 0 and 1, test if the number is larger then 0.5 or smaller this will give you a 50-50%

```js
   var coins;
$(document).on("click", ".battleOne", function() {
      var number = Math.random();
      if (number < 0.5) {
        coins += 5;
        alert("Your dog won the battle!\n+ 5 coins");
      } else {

        coins -= 1;
        alert("Your dog died in battle :(\n- 5 coins");
      }
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button class="battleOne">battleOne</button>
```

if you want different values 40-60 just change the condition to 0.4 or 0.6 depending on what you want have a better %

Answer (score 0):

Try this with the aid of `Math.random`:

```
var coins = 0;
$(document).on("click", ".battleOne", function() {
    var rand = Math.round(Math.random() * 1); // generates an int of 0 or 1
    if (rand) {
        coins += 5;
        alert("Your dog won the battle!\n+ 5 coins");
    } else {
        coins -= 1;
        alert("Your dog died in battle :(\n- 1 coins");
    }
    console.log(coins);
});
```